# How to show unread notification count in Django

Tags: django, getstream-io

I have notifications create from getstream in Django, but I don't know how to show count of unread notifications. Is there any simple way to do this?

In documentation I see mention about it but not how to do this. Maybe I overlooked this.

My notification view look like this:

```py
@login_required
def notification_feed(request):
    enricher = Enrich(request.user)
    context = {}
    feed = feed_manager.get_notification_feed(request.user.id)
    activities = feed.get(limit=25, mark_seen='all')['results']
    activities = enricher.enrich_aggregated_activities(activities)

    return render(request, 'auth/notification_feed.html', {'activities': activities})
```

I need to create global count of unread notifications something like on facebook.

Edit: I found new info about unread and unseen count in getstream documentation but nothing about how to show this. I try to show using {{ activities.unread }} or {{ activities.unseen }} and something like {% for activity in activities %} and then {{  activity.unseen}} but nothing show this info.

Answer (score 0):

From Stream docs:

> At the top level of the JSON response the 'results' field contains an
>   array of Activity Groups, along with overall 'unseen' and 'unread'
>   counts and other metadata about the feed. Within the results array,
>   each Activity Group contains the additional status fields that
>   indicate the group is seen/read.

You should pass the entire response to the template context so that you can use the `unread_count` and `unseen_count` fields.

ie.

```
@login_required
def notification_feed(request):
    enricher = Enrich(request.user)
    context = {}
    feed = feed_manager.get_notification_feed(request.user.id)
    response = feed.get(limit=25, mark_seen='all')
    activities = response['results']
    activities = enricher.enrich_aggregated_activities(activities)
    context = {
        'activities': activities,
        'response': response
    }
    return render(request, 'auth/notification_feed.html', context)
```